# Creating an API with TCP protocol C#

Tags: c#, api, tcp, server, ip-address

My task is the following:

Case study:

In the hospital, there are 10 ICU beds. Each hospital bed is equipped with a ventilator device (respirator), and cardio-monitoring device. All medical devices are connected to the central monitoring system. Each bed is identified with bed_id whereas associated equipment is identified with a static IP address on the hospital network. Central monitoring application should provide observing health parameters for each patient(bed) and remote setting ventilator parameters. Therefore a PC application must be developed and should provide connectivity with all devices in the hospital.

Implementation details:

● Both devices are available on port 2020 via TCP protocol in a request/response and get/set manner and using JSON data format

● Devices IP addresses and associated beds (bed_id) are stored in a JSON file (icu_beds_descriptor.json) that should be already available and that should be loaded from the PC app.

I've done the client part (in WinForms), what is remaining is the API that communicates with the client using TCP protocol. Any help/ideas are appreciated. I'm guessing I need a server instance for each bed and ask for it's device data by sending the devices IP address?

From the first part the following is confusing for me:

- Each bed is identified with bed_id **whereas associated equipment is identified with a static IP address on the hospital network**.

  - Does this mean each bed has a different static IP address or are they all the same?

From the second part, which, I think is connected to the first the following I don't understand:

- Devices IP addresses and associated beds (bed_id) are stored in a JSON file (icu_beds_descriptor.json) that should be already available and that should be loaded from the PC app.

  - Am I supposed to run a service for each bed with predefined (different) IP address? Is that even possible or am I not understanding it right?

Comment: It would have to be a different IP for each bed, otherwise you have network collisions. Static refers to that they are not DHCP assigned, not that they are all the same.

Comment: "what is remaining is the API that communicates with the client using TCP protocol." is a little bit confusing. If you've completed the UI part, what you need is to implement an API that will communicate with the ventilation devices via Tcp/Ip, and will be consumed by your client app. You say you've done the client part. What have you implemented so far?

Comment: Is this a competition question or a job interview assignment? (It's still ok if it is). Look what I've found: https://mlog.club/article/5546979 Can you share the json file here (also the safe values json, which is probably also included in the question) ? These files are important for people to understand the physical network architecture (how devices are connected to the beds). But please let me kindly remind you that, stack overflow is meant mostly to help with problems you have with your already tried code, so, please try something first, and then ask if still required

Comment: @RonBeyer As I am reading this, beds do not have IP adresses. They are "virtual". They merely group a bunch of medical devices, which _do_ have different static IPs. That mapping Device <=> Bed is given in `icu_beds_descriptor.json`.

Comment: @ConsS Just a heads-up: That equipment sounds pretty important. In the sense of "life threatening if fails"-important. So you may want to include check and double check and warn early on (not too generous) timeout or failed connection.